# python indentation problems

Tags: python, indentation

Running the following code gets

> inconsistent indetation detected.

I can't understand the reason.Any ideas?

[This is just for posting the question, because it asks for more details.]

```
class FSM():
    def sel(self):
        self.big=[]
        self.small=[]
        for i in cpop:
            if i.eve>goal:
                self.big.append(i)
            elif i.eve<goal:
                self.small.append(i)
            else:
                print('goal')
                break
    def cross(self):
        self.s1 = randint(0,len(self.big))#nradn
        self.s2 = randint(0,len(self.small))
        self.p1 = self.big[s1]
        self.p2 = self.small[s2]
        self.ch1=self.p1[0,2]+self.p2[2,len(p2)]
        self.ch2=self.p2[0,2]+self.p1[2,len(p1)]
        self.chs.append(ch1)
        self.chs.append(ch2)
    def npop(self):
        self.npop=[]
        self.F={}
        for i in range(0,len(self.chs)):
            self.F[i]= Per(self.chs[i], none)
            self.npop.append(F[i])
        self.F={}
        n+=1
    def cpop(self):
                if n==0:
                        x=Per()
                        z=Per()
                        k=Per()
                        self.cpop=[x,z,k]
                else:
                        self.cpop=self.npop
```

Comment: Have you mixed tabs and spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent from the second line on, where you are describing the `FSM` class

From:

```
class FSM():
def sel(self):
...
```

to

```
class FSM():
  def sel(self):
  ...
```

Also, make sure you don't have a mixure of tabs and spaces.

Since you have

```
def npop(self):
    self.npop=[]
    self.F={}
    for i in range(0,len(self.chs)):
        self.F[i]= Per(self.chs[i], none)
        self.npop.append(F[i])
    self.F={}
    n+=1
def cpop(self):
            if n==0:
                    x=Per()
                    z=Per()
                    k=Per()
                    self.cpop=[x,z,k]
            else:
                    self.cpop=self.npop
```

it looks this is the case in the `cpop` method.

Comment: No, that's how the text was copied.the problem is after def cpop(self):

Comment: then update your question with the proper indentation

Comment: @DogonDiferendal make also sure that you don't have a mixure of tabs and spaces

Comment: What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @DogonDiferendal it means that you are somewhere using spaces to indent and in other places tabs.

Comment: AFAIK, if there is no indent after `class` we get a `expected an indented block` error

Comment: @DogonDiferendal I don't know what editor you are using, but this sounds good. You can also open the file with Notepad or something like that and go through the code with the cursor, removing tabs and writting spaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this indentation:

```
class FSM():
    def sel(self):
        self.big=[]
        self.small=[]
        for i in cpop:
            if i.eve>goal:
                self.big.append(i)
            elif i.eve<goal:
                self.small.append(i)
            else:
                print('goal')
                break

    def cross(self):
        self.s1 = randint(0,len(self.big))#nradn
        self.s2 = randint(0,len(self.small))
        self.p1 = self.big[s1]
        self.p2 = self.small[s2]
        self.ch1=self.p1[0,2]+self.p2[2,len(p2)]
        self.ch2=self.p2[0,2]+self.p1[2,len(p1)]
        self.chs.append(ch1)
        self.chs.append(ch2)

    def npop(self):
        self.npop=[]
        self.F={}
        for i in range(0,len(self.chs)):
            self.F[i]= Per(self.chs[i], none)
            self.npop.append(F[i])
        self.F={}
        n+=1

    def cpop(self):
        if n==0:
            x=Per()
            z=Per()
            k=Per()
            self.cpop=[x,z,k]
        else:
            self.cpop=self.npop
```